# Dialogue becomes jumbled together if I press space bar too quick in my Unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've created a small dialogue scene in Unity for a university project. After a character has finished talking the user presses the space bar to get onto the next part of dialogue. However, if the user presses the space bar too quickly (maybe they want to skip the dialogue) the dialogue between the two characters becomes jumbled together. I tried to implement the code below, but the fluidity of the dialogue is affected too much.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

Below is the code for handling the dialogue. The dialogue itself is contained within a JSON file.

```
 void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        UpdatePanelState();
    }
}
private void InitialisePanels()
{
    leftPanel.characterIsTalking = true;
    rightPanel.characterIsTalking = false;
    leftCharacterActive = !leftCharacterActive;

    leftPanel.Configure(currentEvent.dialogues[stepIndex]);
    rightPanel.Configure(currentEvent.dialogues[stepIndex + 1]);

    StartCoroutine(MasterManager.animationManager.IntroAnimation());

    stepIndex++;
}

private void ConfigurePanels()
{
    if (leftCharacterActive == true)
    {
        leftPanel.characterIsTalking = true;
        rightPanel.characterIsTalking = false;


        leftPanel.Configure(currentEvent.dialogues[stepIndex]);
        rightPanel.ToggleCharacterMask();
    }
    else
    {
        leftPanel.characterIsTalking = false;
        rightPanel.characterIsTalking = true;

        leftPanel.ToggleCharacterMask();
        rightPanel.Configure(currentEvent.dialogues[stepIndex]);
    }
}

void UpdatePanelState()
{
    if (stepIndex < currentEvent.dialogues.Count)
    {
        ConfigurePanels();

        leftCharacterActive = !leftCharacterActive;
        stepIndex++;
    }
    else
    {
        StartCoroutine(MasterManager.animationManager.ExitAnimation());
    }
}
```

}

Due to the fact yield new return(WaitForSeconds(x)) cannot be used in a void method I'm stumped. I've included a screenshot of what happens if the user presses the space bar too quickly before character's dialogue is finished.

[Dialogue Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWtkw.jpg)

How can I fix this problem? Please let me know if you need to see more of the code.

Comment: why not use `yield new return WaitForSeconds(x)` in a coroutine then?

Comment: @ryeMoss ah thank you, did not think of that. Working nicely now.

Comment: if you still need help, please post contents of your panel.Configure method

Comment: Never use `Thread.sleep` unless you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

--- My understanding ---

I would suspect it has something to do with how you use the stepindex to load in from the file.

The way I understand it you want it to gradually load in the text from the JSON file so it appears in the window. But the error happens when more steps are requested at the same time.

Since it sounds like this dialogue is happening as a displayed conversation between the 2 characters where the have a back and forth thing going on.

---

--- A solution ---

**One solution would be to make a check for if the characters are currently having a dialogue**. If they are and space is pressed again, either nothing should happen or it should speed-load in the conversation.

What kind of solution are you looking for? Something to load quickly on extra taps or something so the user has to wait for it to finish?